# What's the difference between MimeHeader and Header in tomcat request?

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

For example, I want to get the authorization header from the request. What's the difference between the following two calls except the return type?

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
request.getCoyoteRequest().getMimeHeaders().getValue("Authorization");
request.getHeader("Authorization");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between those two calls (except the return type).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. They are doing the same job, right? Could you please explain more about under what situation should I use getMimeHeaders instead of getHeader?

Comment: @snowery the one allows you to use a `MessageBytes` object the other the `MessageBytes` converted to a string. Tomcat tries to postpone conversion of the header bytes to a string (maybe it is never used!). So if you don't need the string value use the `MessageBytes` API to save some CPU cycles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!